# Word Count: Ruth

Tags: ruth

Do we have a single definitive original text of the book of Ruth? That is, in the original Hebrew / Aramaic? If so, how many words are in the original, and does this make it the shortest book of the Old Testament?

Comment: This question is not about Christianity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Word counts for every book of the Bible](http://overviewbible.com/word-counts-books-of-bible/), which counted all the words of each book in the original language (and also [explains how he got the data](http://overviewbible.com/bible-word-counts-logos-word-lists/)), *Ruth* has 2,039 words in the original language.

That's 19 more than *Song of Solomon* and also more than *Joel*, *Malachi*, *Zephaniah*, *Jonah*, *Habakkuk*, *Haggai*, *Nahum*, *Obadiah*, and *Philemon*.   So no, it is definitely not the shortest book in the Old Testament.